# Cordova how to install app directly to Android device?

Tags: android, cordova, build, automation, device

in case that i need to test cordova on app i must do this:

- Run cordova build android
- Go into android ADT (Eclipse)
- Clean the project
- And then run from eclipse on device.

Exist some less time consuming plugin or script for this?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just do

```
cordova run android
```

from the command line. See here: [Cordova Command Line docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)